# Why do I have to set the choices manually in a ModelForm when using RadioSelect widget

Tags: django

I have a model with a CharField that has choices assigned to it. I want to display this field in a ModelForm using the RadioSelect() widget.

If I set the widget for the field in the Meta class of the ModelForm, the widget is displayed correctly with all of the choices as radio buttons. (Woo!)

```
class Meta:
    model = Account
    fields = (
        'newsletter_setting',
    )
    widgets = {
        'newsletter_setting': forms.RadioSelect()
    }
```

But If i try to set the widget on the `__init__` method, the widget is rendered with no choices.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AccountEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['newsletter_setting'].widget = forms.RadioSelect()
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repopulate `choices` property of the newly created `RadioSelect`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AccountEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['newsletter_setting'].widget = forms.RadioSelect(
                   choices=self.fields['newsletter_setting'].widget.choices)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you know why this is the case if you set the widget this way? As opposed to in the Meta class? I get why it would be necessary for a vanilla django form, but for a model form it's confusing that you'd have to re-set the choices.

Comment: Windget's `choices` property is set in the parent `__init__` method. Then you define windget in Meta class this works fine. But then you create new widget in `AccountEditForm.__init__` it of course has empty `choices`. So you have to copy choices from old properly initiated widget.